# How to manage ref to top-level actor with Akka

Tags: testing, akka

How to manage properly a reference to a top-level actor.

I use that

```
object MyController extends Controller {
  lazy val supervisor = Akka.system.actorOf(Props[SupervisorActor])
```

But my test fails because the akka system is restarted between tests...

Test code is very similar to play examples :

```
class IntegrationSpec extends Specification  {

  "Application" should {

      "example1" in new WithBrowser(WebDriverFactory(FIREFOX)) {
       …
      }
      "example2" in new WithBrowser(WebDriverFactory(FIREFOX)) {
       …
      }
```

Comment: Can you show some more code, such as your test?

Comment: "But my test fails because the akka system is restarted between tests" sounds like your tests depend on state set by previous tests which ususally is a smell for bad practice

Comment: @jean agree but Play uses some global state. Like Akka.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally found a hack, as `FakeApplication` also use `Global`.
Let me know if there's a better way…

```
object Global extends GlobalSettings {

  var supervisor : ActorRef = null;

  override def onStart(app: Application) {
    supervisor = Akka.system.actorOf(Props[SupervisorActor])

  }
}
```

[edit] As suggested by @jean, I've modified the code to use a named `Actor`, so I don't need anymore to keep a reference in an `object`.

```
override def onStart(app: Application) {
  Akka.system.actorOf(Props[SupervisorActor], "supervisor")
}
```

And I could retrieve the actor with :

```
context.actorSelection("/user/supervisor")
```